# Dual boot system (Windows10-Ubuntu 18.04) on Uefi pc?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, windows-10, mbr

I own a Aspire E 15 laptotp where I installed Ubuntu 18.04 because I fell in love with this OS.

I later discovered that games doesn't run very well on this system because they are simply not designed to, even with compatibility layers like Wine the performances reached are terrible and the hybrid GPU design of my pc doesn't allow me to fully experience the dedicated Nvidia card.

My laptop uses UEFI and some people told me that I would never be able to install W10 in a double boot configuration with Ubuntu, is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true.  I have a Dell 311AD desktop with UEFI which is a dual booter with Windows and Ubuntu.

It's been over a year since I booted into Windows but it worked fine when I set it up as I was transitioning to Linux.